# Pass Svelte Component as Props

Tags: reactjs, properties, svelte

I am pretty new to the `svelte` environment,
I have some react code and try to convert them as svelte for the learning purpose.

In the react, we can pass a string or React Node as props.

```
<TabPane
name="profile"
title={<img src="images/profile.svg" alt="Profile" />}
key="1"
>
    {/** some code **/} 
</TabPane>
```

I am trying to use the same code in svelte, but it throws an error.
[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't do this in Svelte.

You'll have to figure out how you can achieve the same outcome with the APIs available in Svelte.

For example, you can use [`<slot>`](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/slots):

```html
<TabPane
  name="profile"
  key="1"
>
  <img slot="title" src="images/profile.svg" alt="Profile" />
  <!-- some code, eg: -->
  <div>Some code here</div>
</TabPane>
```

```html
<!-- filename: TabPane.svelte -->

<h1>
  <slot name="title" />
</h1>

<slot />
```

---

The element with attribute `slot="title"` will be inserted into `<slot name="title">`

and the rest of the elements will be inserted into `<slot />`

---

This is equivalent in React:

```
function TabPane({ title, children }) {
  return (
    <>
       <h1>{title}</h1>
       {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

If you want to pass in only string for the title, you could wrap the string around with `<svelte:fragment>` so that you can add the `slot="title"` attribute

```html
<TabPane
  name="profile"
  key="1"
>
  <svelte:fragment slot="title">
    string title here
  <svelte:fragment>
  <!-- some code, eg: -->
  <div>Some code here</div>
</TabPane>
```

---

Reference:

- Svelte tutorial: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/slots
- Video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwYgOU0WmVk&list=PLoKaNN3BjQX3mxDEVG3oGJx2ByXnue_gR&index=59

Comment: Is `<svelte:fragment>` is allow only the string?

Comment: If you're familiar with React's fragments (i.e., `<> </>`), you can use `<svelte:fragment>` the same way. Anything can go inside of it.

Comment: For anyone coming across this: you don’t need to use svelte:fragment for the string. Just use export let variables or the forthcoming props$ rune. You only need slots when you are passing HTML or components into a component. You use svelte:fragment if you want the contents of your slot to show up without other surrounding elements like <div>s, just like react, which is useful sometimes. Happy coding!

Answer (score 20):

In many cases you'll want to use slots as Tan Li Hau suggested. However, it is possible to pass components as props. For this, we are going to make use of `<svelte:component>`. It's quite restrictive, but it's a possibility.

https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_component

## `<svelte:component>`

Normally, you'd use `<svelte:component>` like this:

```
<script>
  import Component from './component.svelte'
</script>

<svelte:component this={Component} foo={bar} />
```

The above is equivalent to this:

```
<script>
  import Component from './component.svelte'
</script>

<Component foo={bar} />
```

### Passing down components through props

This means we can actually pass down components through props.

```
<!-- app.svelte -->

<script>
  import ComponentA from './component-a.svelte'
  import ComponentB from './component-b.svelte'
</script>

<ComponentA foo={ComponentB} />
```

And render the component…

```
<!-- component-a.svelte -->

<script>
  export let foo
</script>

<svelte:component this={foo} />
```

### Caveats

Note there are a few things you can't do:

- Set props on the component passed down through props
- Pass down components which children through props
- Or do pretty much anything else with the component passed down as a prop

Svelte may not even be designed to do this (even though it works). So yeah, unless you really need this, use slots. But now you know this is possible.